# In sqlplus how how to assign the result of PL/SQL function to a variable if the result is a varchar2(n) with n> n

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

```
CREATE function f4001 return varchar2
is
begin
   return rpad('*', 4100, '*');
end;


select f4001() from dual;
```

> doesn't work: sql buffer to small

therefore to assign a sql variable I use that:

```
variable buffer varchar(32000);
execute :buffer = f4001();
```

I can print it:

```
print buffer
```

but I can't prompt it. Or use itas an argument for a powershell function:

```
 host powershell echo '&buffer'
```

for that reason I have to use 'define' or 'column'.

define :  I have'nt find a way to give the result of a pl/sql function with define. All I can do is:

```
 define buffer= cte
```

column: work only for varchar(N) with N>4000.

```
  column buffer new_value buffer
  select f3999 as buffer from dual
```

> OK

```
  select f4001 as buffer from dual
```

> buffer to small

Answer (score 0):

Replacing varchar2 type with clob did helped me to get rid o "buffer too small" problem.

So, in other words, try this:

```
CREATE or replace function f4001 return clob ...
```

and

```
variable buffer clob;
```

Comment: But I would like to the buffer in host powershell buffer. I can't do that I using a clob

Answer (score 0):

The [CREATE FUNCTION](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/CREATE-FUNCTION-statement.html#GUID-B71BC5BD-B87C-4054-AAA5-213E856651F2) documentation says:

> The database derives the length, precision, or scale of the return value from the environment from which the function is called.

Your environment is SQL, and - in it - varchar2 is restricted to 4000 characters.

What to do?

- If your database version is 12c or higher, talk to DBA and see whether they can set `MAX_STRING_SIZE` to `EXTENDED` (then max size is 32767 and not 4000), or
- Switch to `CLOB` datatype